# Как автоматически секционировать таблицу по дате?

Tags: sql, oracle, partition

Имеется вот такая вот таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID NUMBER(*) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  TEXT VARCHAR2(4000),
  DATE_CREATE DATE DEFAULT sysdate NOT NULL
)
```

Нужно сделать по ней автоматическое секционирование по столбцу `DATE_CREATE`. Интервал - один день, чтобы на следующий день автоматически создавалась новая партиция и следовательно, в нее заносили данные за этот день.

Слышал что в 11g эту реализацию добавили, пытался разобраться, но как доходит до `partition ... values less than (..)`, то сразу теряюсь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
create table test(id number, date_create date default sysdate not null)
partition by range (date_create)
INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
(PARTITION FIRST VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2016-11-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN'))
);
```

PS в первую партицию (секцию) попадут **все** дни `< 2016-11-30 00:00:00`

Из [доки](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm#insertedID2):

> You must specify at least one range partition using the PARTITION
>   clause.

**UPDATE:**

вместо `select * from tab partition(p1);` можно воспользоваться след. запросом, который должен прочитать только одну дневную партицию и вернуть из нее записи:

```
select * from test
where date_create between to_date('2016-11-29','yyyy-mm-dd')
                      and to_date('2016-11-30','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: у меня был такой вариант, просто не совсем понимаю его реализацию, получается с начало мы создаем начальную партицию на текущий день и потом уже происходит автоматическое создание?

Comment: @D.Antov, да, Oracle "требует", чтобы присутствовала хотя бы одна "range partition". Более поздние партиции создадутся автоматически.

Comment: возникает такой вопрос: партиции создаются неименованные, как в следствии этого делать по ним выборку?стандартное `select * from tab partition(p1)` не подходит

Comment: @D.Antov, а вы "Oracle partition pruning" не доверяете? В смысле если указать в WHERE соотв. условие, то Oracle не будет читать те партиции, которые ему не нужны...

Comment: Хотел бы отметить, что существует то ли баг, то ли фича: если в столбце секционирования будет дата 31.12.9999, то может появиться ошибка ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0. Судя по всему, это не Ваш случай, но мало ли. Нам пришлось откзааться от интервального автоматического секцонирования именно из-за этого. Можно почитать способы обхода https://www.jamescoyle.net/knowledge/2482-oracle-database-interval-partitioning-and-virtual-columns

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу уважаемого коллеги [@MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597727).

Допустим, у таблицы в вопросе есть дочерняя таблица с внешним ключом. Так как в этой таблице записей обычно несравненно больше, чем в родительской, то естестственно, встаёт потребность её тоже партиционировать. Причём, логично, что все записи в дочерней таблице, относящиеся к первичным ключам одной родительской партиции, должны быть также в одной дочерней партиции.

Но в дочерней таблице столбца `DATE_CREATE` нет, или он есть, но может иметь другую дату. Для этого в 11g была введена новая возможность - [Reference Partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm#CACIHDII), но было одно ограничение:

> Interval partitioning cannot be used with reference partitioning.

То есть, референциальное партиционирование по интервалу, как в соседнем ответе, было недоступно. Начиная с версии 12c это ограничение было снято, см. [Interval-Reference Partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-C7A9BAD4-E4C9-4765-88C5-51AC7E97BAF1.htm#GUID-3FDA481F-1DCE-4550-92BE-2F444D97EC6C).

Как это работает на [вопроизводимом примере](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=05257565e1dfbe7dd0a9777fb57acfcc):

```
create table t1 (
    id number primary key, 
    memo varchar2(16), 
    created date)
partition by range (created) interval (numToDSInterval (1, 'day')) (
    partition def_part values less than (date'1900-01-01'))
/
create table t2 (
    id number primary key, 
    t1id number NOT NULL, 
    memo varchar2(16), 
    created date,
    constraint t2fk foreign key (t1id) references t1 (id)) 
partition by reference (t2fk)
/
```

Заметьте, ограничение `NOT NULL` у внешнего ключа - оно обязательно, так как "безхозных" дочерних записей быть не должно.

При вставке будут автоматически созданы новые партиции в обоих таблицах:

```
insert into t1 values (1,    't1 parent row 1', date'2021-01-01');
insert into t2 values (1, 1, 't2 row 1  ref 1', date'2021-01-01');
insert into t2 values (2, 1, 't2 row 2  ref 1', date'2021-01-31');

select table_name, partition_name
from   user_tab_partitions
where table_name in ('T1', 'T2')
order by 1, 2;

TABLE_NAME       PARTITION_NAME  
---------------- ----------------
T1               DEF_PART        
T1               SYS_P10945      
T2               DEF_PART        
T2               SYS_P10945
```

---

К [комментарию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597725/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5#comment807656_597727):

> возникает такой вопрос, партиции создаются неименованные, как в следствии этого делать по ним выборку? стандартное `select * from tab partition(p1)`

Чтобы выбрать партицию не зная её имени, укажите ключ партиции в клаузе `PARTITION FOR` [(см. partition_extension_clause)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6), эффект будет тот же:

```
select * 
from t2
where exists (
    select null 
    from t1 partition for (date'2021-01-01')
    where t1.id = t2.t1id);

        ID       T1ID MEMO             CREATED            
---------- ---------- ---------------- -------------------
         1          1 t2 row 1  ref 1  2021-01-01 00:00:00
         2          1 t2 row 2  ref 1  2021-01-31 00:00:00
```